# Yii2 AccessControl permissions denied on get image

Tags: php, permissions, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working on small module on yii2 advanced template where I need to upload images. The upload work fine but when i try to get the uploaded image ad render them in a view i receive this error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not     allowed to perform this action.' in     /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:15    1
Stack trace:
#0     /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php(13    4): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(269): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php(108):     yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#6 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(152):     yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#7 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454):     yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(93):     yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#9     /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(109):     yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-    >handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#11 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve     the request     "var/www/html/yii_advance/common/upload/slider_image/116.png".' in     /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:460
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('var/www/html/yi...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 /var/www/html/yii_advance/backend/web/index.php(18):     yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not     found.' in     /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/yii_advance/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/yii_advance/backend/web/index.php(18):              yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

This happens only for the request image, the page are correctly rendered, the controller behaviors are:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' =>[
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                '*' => ['post', 'get']
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

The image are request on a form which I use for create and update:
...

```
<?php if($model->imageFile):?>
    <span><?=$model->imageFile ?></span>
    <?= Html::img($model->imageFile) ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

...

If I open the src of image in another browser tab I've not the same problem, permission's files are set to 777 for prevent errors.
How i can do to see the image inside the page?
Thanks

Comment: what is the value of $model->imageFile ?

Comment: The full path of the image

Comment: yii_advance/common/upload/slider_image/116.png is this the path ? if yes than it will not get read by the browser any how .. your images should be in the web root or its sub dir's, which is frontend/web/

Comment: @KandarpPatel I've chenge the as /var/www/yii_advance/frontend/web/images/etc. but I'm working on backend and i need to save in frontend/web, how i can access to frontend/web from backend?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-link-backend-frontend.md refer this

Answer (score 0):

You may did not add a rule for the error action.
Add following rule to grant access to the actionError on the SiteController:

```
'rules'=>[
//...
    [
        'actions'=>['error'],
        'allow'=>true,
    ],
//...
]
```